# sql update transaction deadloack

Tags: sql, transactions

I have an application which updates average 60 records per second in an sql table using transaction. If I run multiple instances of this application, transaction is deadlocked. Is there any way, if any transaction on, the other application process is queued and execute after the current transaction.

Comment: What RDBMS? What is the table structure (including indexes) and `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: My Update statement is below <br/>
`UPDATE CreditLimit
SET CreditLimitBalance = CreditLimitBalance + (@BusinessSellPrice / 100) WHERE ClientID = @ClientID` 
Table structure <br/>
`ID int
BusinessID int (Index Asc)
ClientID int (Index Asc)
MobileID int
BatchCLI int  (Index Asc)
CreditLimit money
CreditLimitBalance money
AlertThresholdPercentage smallmoney
EmailThresholdPercentage smallmoney
AlertEmail nvarchar(255)
AlertMobileNumber varchar(50)
IsActive bit
LastEmailAlertSend datetime
LastMobileAlertSend datetime
islocked bit`

Comment: I set below statement above update query and issue solved. And data are updated correctly.
'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;'